# Is logging into a bank account with a VPN more dangerous than without VPN?

Tags: vpn

If I need to log in my bank account, the VPN company can capture of my passwords.

Isn't it more dangerous?

Comment: Only if your bank does not use HTTPS. And if your bank does not use HTTPS for their online services - change bank.

Comment: If you call your next-door neighbor on the phone, then the police and the phone company can listen in. But if you go out on the sidewalk and yell, a lot more people will be able to hear.

Comment: Welcome. You're missing a word in your title: Is *what* more dangerous without a VPN? Also, please be more specific about what you consider "dangerous."

Answer (score 1):

All banks should be using [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) on their websites.  This is often indicated by an image of a lock in your browser's address bar.  HTTPS provides encryption between you and the bank's website.  This means no one between you and the bank can read the data being transferred.

A VPN provides a secure, encrypted tunnel between you and the VPN's endpoint.  After leaving that endpoint, there is no longer any encryption provided by the VPN.  If you were using a standard HTTP website, then the VPN provider can read the data you are sending back and forth.  If you are using a HTTPS website, then the encryption mentioned in the previous paragraph still applies and the VPN provider cannot read the data.

There are a lot of VPN providers popping up in the last few years.  Their focus is more on anonymity then security.  They can hide some aspects of your internet activity from everyone between you and them, but that is all.  They are also useful for changing your perceived location, so you can connect to websites from countries that block them.  In addition to that, you dont know what information they are collecting on you.  These VPN endpoints often get blocked by websites, as well as other issues.  Personally, I do not think they are worthwhile.